# Build APK getting crashed all the time after successful manual installation

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

After updating to `Android Studio 3.0.1`, my `app-debug.apk` crashed all the time after successful manual installation.

My application is running absolutely fine in emulator & also in the device which is connected to the PC. The only problem I got when I try to install it manually & after successful installation it's getting crashed all the time.

**N.B:**

- I already disable Instant Run.
- I build the APK through Android Studio's Build APK(S) function.
- I tried to install the `app-debug.apk` manually in an Android Oreo Device.
- In the exact same device, it runs fine when i connected it with my PC & build the app through Android Studio.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the logcat to find out what is wrong. Most properly is that you use a new API on a old device.

Comment: How could i check the logcat when i tried to install apk manually ? & i am using OnePlus 3T for testing purpose.

Comment: If you check the bottom of your Android Studio you should see the Logcat tab. You just need to connect your mobile via USB.

Comment: Are you sure you are installing the good apk ? In Android studio 3, the apk files are not generated in the same folders than before, maybe you made the same mistake than me !